# Grunt Error : unexpeceted token { syntax error

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

Hi I am trying to learn grunt tutorial from youtube and I am following the same instruction as mention in the video.

But while running the command grunt in my system I am getting the error , which I am not able to resolve it.

Below is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shreyansh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "running grunt test",
  "main": "index.html",
  "author": "shreyansh",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = funtion(grunt) {


        grunt.initConfig({

            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

            cssmin: {
                combine:{
                    files:{
                        'Project/css/main.css': [ 'file-upload.css']
                    }
                }
            } 

        });


        grunt.LoadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');     

        grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin'])

};
```

**Error : -**

*Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.*

I tried to look for the similar errors questions from stackoverflow but no luck.
Any help is appreciated as I am using grunt first time

Thanks

Comment: It's a typo: `funtion`

Comment: Thanks , was not able to found the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the typo in line 1 of your gruntfile, change `funtion` to `function`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        cssmin: {
            combine:{
                files:{
                    'Project/css/main.css': [ 'file-upload.css']
                }
            }
        }

    });


    grunt.LoadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin'])

};
```